# Sendgrid inbound webhook with node and multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid

I'm trying to store emails from sendgrid via the inbound webhook using node, express and multer. There is an example on sendgrids site as below:

```
var express = require('express');
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer();
var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.use(multer());
});
app.post('/parse', upload.array('files', 3) function (req, res) {
  var from = req.body.from;
  var text = req.body.text;
  var subject = req.body.subject;
  var num_attachments = req.body.attachments;
  for (i = 1; i <= num_attachments; i++){
    var attachment = req.files['attachment' + i];
    // attachment will be a File object
  }
});

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

This code throws an error when an email with an attachment is sent. The error is "unexpected field". I assume that the declaration for array.upload("files",3) is where the issue lies. Has anybody solved this?

Comment: Were you able to find the solution?

Comment: Switched inbound email to mail gun. We send mail out with Sendgrid, and mapped incoming email to Mailgun. Mailgun have better handling of attachments. They give you a URL, we just pull the attachment from that URL and store it. In short we simply fetch each URL (attachment) and store it on the fly, Mailgun has a nice set-up for inbound email and they charge a very small amount for it, so it was easier to do this way back when we had this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by using .any() when you don't the field name (see [documentation for any()](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#any)

Here's an example code

```
app.post('/parse', upload.any() function (req, res) {
  var from = req.body.from;
  var text = req.body.text;
  var subject = req.body.subject;
  var num_attachments = req.body.attachments;
  for (i = 1; i <= num_attachments; i++){
    var attachment = req.files['attachment' + i];
    // attachment will be a File object
  }
});
```